# What is the best way to implement exponential retry in C# Azure Function 4.x with a Service Bus as a trigger?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I’m planning to create an **C# Azure Function 4.x** with a **Service Bus** Topic Queue as a **trigger**. The function will take the message and may transform the data and writes it to a DB. There will be multiple functions with different logic. In case of a **temporary exception** e.g. DB connection problems, I want to **retry** the operation after some time again. Ideally, some kind of **exponential backoff** with variable intervals e.g. after 1sec, 5sec, 15sec, 30sec, 1m, 5m, 30m … until the maximum retry is reached and the message is sent to the **dead letter queue**.

I read multiple documentations including retry policies [which are deprecated for service bus triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp).
The best I found in the docs is the build in retries for [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp). But I’m concerned that this retry is at function level and keep the **function awake/blocked during the waiting time between the retry intervals**. Hence, the function wouldn’t do anything, just sleep and wait for the next retry interval, but you would still have to pay for the idle time since the function is actually running. Moreover, the function is blocked and can’t accept more messages by the service bus trigger. If you have multiple functions blocked by retries at once it may exceed the `maxConcurrentCalls` or `maxConcurrentSessions` not sure which one or even if it’s the case tho.

Another approach would be to write the retry handling myself and use the queue instead of the built-in retry binding. [Here is a good example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/DeadletterQueue/Program.cs) for it:

It basically clones the original message in case of an exception and puts it back into the queue with a scheduled time. And it marks the original message as completed/consumed. The cloned message is then consumed again if the scheduled time has arrived.
In this way, the Azure function is not blocked until the scheduled time has arrived because it’s managed in the service bus.

**But shouldn’t there be a built-in feature by Azure, or is that actually done under the hood when using the retry binding as described above, so my concerns are invalid?!**

**TL;DR**

What is the best way to implement exponential retry in Azure Function with a Service Bus as a trigger?
It should not cost money during the time the Function is idle and wait for the next try.

Comment: Hi Moo, this is an important question. But you may be getting downvoted because StackOverflow is not meant for opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking your ServiceBusTrigger function and initiating a [Durable Task Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) Orchestrator function. The Orchestrator can call as many Activity functions as needed, and you can use the RetryOptions class that is configured to however you'd like to attempt to retry.